# How to indent pictures on Wordpress blog?

Tags: images

I'm new to Wordpress; sorry if this sounds like an obvious question.  I know absolutely no programming at all.

[Here](http://thebigmansworld.com/2015/07/12/healthy-no-bake-cheesecake-cups/) is a blog post so you can see what I'm talking about.  See how the picture doesn't line up straight with the title/words?

Now here is [my blog](http://eatyournuts.com/2016/01/chocolate-maple-date-hazelcups-raw-vegan-paleo/).  My pictures line up completely straight with the words in the post, no indents.  I'm using the same theme as the other blog.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You are likely looking to make some CSS edits to your theme.  If you are not a programmer, I would recommend getting your feet wet with some of that before diving into edits on your live website.  Backup, backup, backup are steps 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that on those images you're using `aligncenter` in the content and on your blog you have `alignnone`. Center aligning does just that, centers your content in the container putting margins on either side.

You need to go to your editor, click each image, then click **edit**:

[image: Edit Image]

This will bring you to a media settings page where you can change the position of the image. You want to go from `Left` to `None`:

[image: Aligned Left to None]

Comment: I've tried Left align, Center align and None but most of the pictures (unless they are skinny) don't change position at all.  :/

Comment: If you go to `Text` mode in your editor - do you see alignleft after updating?

Comment: Currently it is set at "None" for alignment... but when I change it to Center or Left align, it looks the exact same in the preview.